# ExcludePattern is not working for Swagger URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, interceptor

I have an interceptor which is responsible for validating the security token present in the request header. But for Swagger, I do not want to validate that part. So I added the URL in the exclude pattern of the interceptor but it is not working. Following is my code for exclusion:

```
    @Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new AuthorizationInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**")
            .excludePathPatterns("/health*","/**/swagger-ui.html/**");
}
```

but this is not working as I am getting the authorization error from the interceptor. What is going wrong here? the deault Swagger URL is: http://localhost:3000/swagger-ui.html

**EDIT**: I saw that the swagger-ui.html page exists inside the META_INF/resources folder of springfox jar. So I addded the following `excludePathPatterns("/health*", "classpath:/META-INF/resources/**", "**/swagger-ui.html")` but that also did not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I set it up:

```
    registry.addInterceptor(new CustomInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").
            excludePathPatterns(
                    "/v2/api-docs",
                    "/swagger-resources/**",
                    "/swagger-ui.html",
                    "/webjars/**"
            );
```